# Kafka streams headers support

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In our application the producer is sending different data types and the it may happen that a partition can have different datatype objects as we didn't want to partition based on datatype.

In kafka Streams I was trying to use headers.
Producer is adding header to the BytesObject and pushing the data to kafka.

Header are say, a particular dataType(customObject).
Now based of header I want to parse deserialize the BytesObject received in kafka streams but I am bounded by using processorInterface where I have to pass the actual deserializer

Is there any way I don't have to specify the deserialize beforehand then based on header in processorContext for a record received I can deserialize  the Objects

```java
public class StreamHeaderProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<String, Bytes>{

    @Override
    public void process(String key, Bytes value) {
        Iterator<Header> it = context().headers().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Header head = it.next();
            if (head.key().equals("dataType")) {
                String headerValue = new String(head.value());
                if (headerValue.equals("X")) {

                } else if(headerValue.equals("Y")) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don's set Serdes in `StreamsConfig` and don't set Serdes on `builder.stream(..., Consumed.with(/*Serdes*/))` Kafka Streams will use `ByteArraySerde` by default and thus key and value is copied into `byte[]` arrays as data types. (Similar for using Processor API, and don't set a Serde on `topology.addSource(...)`.)

Thus, you can apply a `Processor` or `Transformer` on the data stream, inspect the header and call the corresponding deserializer in your own code. You need to know all possible data type in advance.

```java
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
    // add corresponding deserializers for all expected types (eg, String)
    private StringDeserializer stringDeserializer = new StringDeserializer();

    // other methods omitted

    void process(byte[] key, byte[] value) {
        // inspect header
        if (header.equals("StringType") {
            // get `context` via `init()` method
            String stringValue = stringDeserializer.deserialize(context.topic(), value);
            // similar for `key`

            // apply processing logic for String type
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks ..I went with the same approach by giving ByteSerializer which wraps the bytes array and then based on header send data dowstream procerssors.

Comment: Also how to forward to different topics based on headers?

Comment: You should do a new question for this. But you can try `branch()` or `to(TopicNameExtractor)`.

Comment: If using state store, branch() isn't an option.

Comment: Why would `branch()` (or `split()` for newer versions) not be an option? Of course, you might need to copy the headers into the value first, and remove them again after `branch()`.